# Simple-Schema for Meteor, method not returning a Number

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've seen lots of questions related to Meteor methods not being found but none of the solutions work for me. I am trying to implement and auto-increment `_id` field in my collection.

Here are my files:

`server/methods.js`

```
Meteor.methods({

getNextSequence: function(counter_name) {

    if (Counters.findOne({ _id: counter_name }) == 0) {

        Counters.insert({
            _id: counter_name,
            seq: 0
        });

        console.log("Initialized counter: " + counter_name + " with a sequence value of 0.");
        return 0;
    }

    Counters.update({
        _id: counter_name
    }, {
        $inc: {
            seq: 1
        }
    });

    var ret = Counters.findOne({ _id: counter_name });
    console.log(ret);
    return ret.seq;
}

});
```

and 
`lib/collections/simple-schemas.js`

```
Schemas = {};

Schemas.Guests = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: Number,
        label: "ID",
        min: 0,
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert && Meteor.isClient) {
                Meteor.call("getNextSequence", "guest_id", function(error, result) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("getNextSequence Error: " + error);
                    } else {
                        console.log(result);
                        return result;
                    }
                });
            }
            // ELSE omitted intentionally
        }
    }
});

Guests.attachSchema(Schemas.Guests);
```

I'm getting an error that I'm assuming is coming from Simple-Schema and it's saying `Error: ID must be a Number`, but my code is returning a number isn't it? Also my `console.log` messages are not showing up, the ones in the Meteor.methods call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `_id` an `optional: true` setting. The `autoValue` will give it a real value but the *required* check is failing before it reaches the `autoValue`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure that 'autoValue' will be set correctly with an asynchronous call like that.

Comment: Something odd. It still fails when I set `optional: true`, but when I change the type from `Number` to `String` it works..well, at least it doesn't fail.

Comment: @MichaelFloyd I put some more console messages in my callback to confirm that it IS returning a number. But I'm still getting an `ID must be a number error`. Could this be a sync versus async problem?

Comment: Possibly. I think the right way to do this is to have the `autoValue` code only run on the server and call `getNextSequence` synchronously.

Comment: Thanks, I will post an update soon, I have begun looking at tutorials to do it synchronously. Your answer is king for now!

Answer (score 0):

The argument you have passed inside the Meteor.call is not a number, but a string `"guest_id"`. You should pass `this.value` as it references the value passed to the key `_id` .

Your Meteor.call function would like the following:

```
Meteor.call("getNextSequence", this.value, function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("getNextSequence Error: " + error);
                } else {
                    console.log(result);
                    return result;
                }
            });
```

Comment: However my counters were initialized in this way: `Counters.insert({
        _id: "guest_id",
        seq: 0
    });
    Counters.insert({
        _id: "party_id",
        seq: 0
    });` inside `server/fixtures.js`